# Web app for trying out C# code snippets running on Linux with Mono?

Tags: gratis, web-apps, software-development, c#, mono

Is there a "fiddle"-style web application to try out C# code (or possibly other .NET/CLI-compatible languages) on a Linux system?

For C#, I only know [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/), and it appears to run on Windows (judging by e.g. the value of [`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd169646.aspx)). I am basically looking for an equivalent web-based service accessible for free, but running on Linux with Mono.